# Exception in thread django-main-thread: Traceback (most recent call last):

Tags: python, django

I started my first project in python-django and like any beginner I've been running into an error for 2 days already. When i run my server i get the error :

```
Exception in thread django-main-thread:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python311\Lib\threading.py", line 1038, in _bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "C:\Python311\Lib\threading.py", line 975, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "C:\Python311\Lib\site-packages\django\utils\autoreload.py", line 64, in wrapper
    fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Python311\Lib\site-packages\django\core\management\commands\runserver.py", line 133, in inner_run
    self.check(display_num_errors=True)
  File "C:\Python311\Lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 485, in check
    all_issues = checks.run_checks(
                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Python311\Lib\site-packages\django\core\checks\registry.py", line 88, in run_checks
    new_errors = check(app_configs=app_configs, databases=databases)
                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Python311\Lib\site-packages\django\core\checks\urls.py", line 14, in check_url_config
    return check_resolver(resolver)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Python311\Lib\site-packages\django\core\checks\urls.py", line 24, in check_resolver
    return check_method()
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Python311\Lib\site-packages\django\urls\resolvers.py", line 494, in check
    for pattern in self.url_patterns:
                   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Python311\Lib\site-packages\django\utils\functional.py", line 57, in __get__
    res = instance.__dict__[self.name] = self.func(instance)
                                         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Python311\Lib\site-packages\django\urls\resolvers.py", line 715, in url_patterns
    patterns = getattr(self.urlconf_module, "urlpatterns", self.urlconf_module)
                       ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Python311\Lib\site-packages\django\utils\functional.py", line 57, in __get__
    res = instance.__dict__[self.name] = self.func(instance)
                                         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Python311\Lib\site-packages\django\urls\resolvers.py", line 708, in urlconf_module
    return import_module(self.urlconf_name)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Python311\Lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1206, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1178, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1149, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 690, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 940, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 241, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "C:\Users\rt-enterprises\OneDrive\RTSOFTT\PROJECTS\Python Projects\JT_ORDER-FILES\JT_Order\JT_Order\urls.py", line 22, in <module>
    path(r'^',include('JTOrderApp.urls')),
              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Python311\Lib\site-packages\django\urls\conf.py", line 38, in include
    urlconf_module = import_module(urlconf_module)
                     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Python311\Lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1206, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1178, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1149, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 690, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 940, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 241, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "C:\Users\rt-enterprises\OneDrive\RTSOFTT\PROJECTS\Python Projects\JT_ORDER-FILES\JT_Order\JTOrderApp\urls.py", line 4, in <module>
    from .views import companyApi
  File "C:\Users\rt-enterprises\OneDrive\RTSOFTT\PROJECTS\Python Projects\JT_ORDER-FILES\JT_Order\JTOrderApp\views.py", line 6, in <module>
    from JTOrderApp import Companies, Supplies, Drivers, Camions, Products, Measures, Orders
ImportError: cannot import name 'Companies' from 'JTOrderApp' (C:\Users\rt-enterprises\OneDrive\RTSOFTT\PROJECTS\Python Projects\JT_ORDER-FILES\JT_Order\JTOrderApp\__init__.py)
```

My environment:

```
asgiref             3.6.0
charset-normalizer  3.1.0
Django              4.2
django-cors-headers 3.14.0
djangorestframework 3.14.0
idna                3.4
mysqlclient         2.1.1
pip                 22.3.1
pytz                2023.3
setuptools          65.5.0
sqlparse            0.4.3
tzdata              2023.3
urllib3             1.26.15
```

Here is my **urls.py** file:

```
from django.urls import path
from JTOrderApp import views
urlpattern=[
    path(r'^company$', views.companyApi),
    path(r'^company/([0-9]+)$',views.companyApi)
]
```

and **JTOrderApp.urls.py**

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path,include
urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path(r'^',include('JTOrderApp.urls')),
]
```

my **views.py** file

```
@csrf_exempt
def companyApi(request, id=0):
    if request.method=='GET':
        companies = Companies.objects.all()
        companies_serializer=CompanySerializers(companies,many=True)
        return JsonResponse(companies_serializer.data,safe=False)
    elif request.method=='POST':
        company_data=JSONParser().parse(request)
        companies_serializer=CompanySerializers(data=company_data)
        if companies_serializer.is_valid():
            companies_serializer.save()
            return JsonResponse("Ajouté avec succès",safe=False)
        return JsonResponse("Erreur d'ajout",safe=False)
    elif request.method=='PUT':
        company_data=JSONParser().parse(request)
        company = Companies.objects.get(CompanyId=company_data['CompanyId'])
        companies_serializer=CompanySerializers(company,data=company_data)
        if companies_serializer.is_valid():
            companies_serializer.save()
            return JsonResponse("Mise à jour avec succès",safe=False)
        return JsonResponse("Erreur de mise jour",safe=False)               
    elif request.method=='DELETE':
        company = Companies.objects.get(CompanyId=id)
        company.delete()
        return JsonResponse("Elément supprimé avec succès",safe=False)
```

and finally my **setting.py** file :

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    # 'JTOrderApp.apps.JtorderappConfig',
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'rest_framework',
    'corsheaders',
    'JTOrderApp',
]
```

Here is the structure of my project:
[image]
What is the cause of the error please.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Make sure you correctly import `Companies`.

Comment: Normally your models are stored in **models.py** so maybe it should just be `from JTOrderApp.models import Companies, ...` instead of `from JTOrderApp import Companies, ...`.

Comment: @raphael, i have tried your suggestion, but nothing. It return the same error.

Comment: I guess I'd need to see your folder structure, but is `JTOrderApp` an app, or is it the project?  Is it in the same folder as **settings.py**?  If so, then it should not be included in `INSTALLED_APPS`, and your **views.py** should be in the directory for the app (`python manage.py startapp ...`) not in the project level directory (`django-admin startproject ...`)

Comment: @raphael, , I edited my question and you can see the structure of my project. Also, I made ```python manage.py startapp ....``` to create `JTOrderAp`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution to my problem.
First I changed

- JTOrderApp.urls.py

```
from django.urls import re_path
from JTOrderApp import views
urlpattern=[
    re_path(r'^company$', views.companyApi),
    re_path(r'^company/([0-9]+)$',views.companyApi)
]
```

- my urls.py file also:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path,re_path,include
urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    re_path(r'^',include('JTOrderApp.urls')),
]
```

So where I use r'^', I take re_path instead of path to avoid errors.

Second, and this is where I had my problem; my models import was not good in my `serializers.py` file, I changed `from JTOrderApp import Companies` to `from JTOrderApp.models import Companies` (rookie mistake, be careful when import).
Now everything is fine, I thank you all for your interventions which helped me to find my solution.

Answer (score 0):

Your project folder structure is fine.  What was and is still confusing is your **urls.py** files.  I think you have them reversed.

The cause of the error, I believe, is a circular import in your **JTOrderApp.urls.py** where you are doing `path(r'^',include('JTOrderApp.urls')),`, in other words you are importing `JTOrderApp` urls into `JTOrderApp` urls.py file.

**Solution:**

Make *this* your **JT_Order.urls.py**

```py
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path,include
urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path(r'^',include('JTOrderApp.urls')),
]
```

and make the following your **JTOrderApp.urls.py**:

```py
from django.urls import path
from JTOrderApp import views
urlpattern=[
    path(r'^company$', views.companyApi),
    path(r'^company/([0-9]+)$',views.companyApi)
]
```

Suggestion:
When starting a new project I always call the project **config** as in

```py
django-admin startproject config .
```

because that's where all the configuration files are (**settings.py**) and the *root* urls.